# Assigning output number to X output

Tags: xrandr, multi-monitor, xmonad, tiling-wm

I am trying to manually assign an output index to my X output (monitor).

`xrandr` does that for output 0, with the option `--primary`, what I am missing is an option `--secondary`.

**Background**: I'm happy with my outputs' placement in the virtual screen, because of how I expect my mouse cursor to move across  monitors. My WM has keyboard shortcuts to focus a monitor, and the monitor getting index 1 is not the one I want (three monitors). It's fixable in the WM, but it'd be cleaner to tell X who is 1 and who is 2.